# Copying of depended-upon dlls in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, reference, projects-and-solutions, class-library, dll

In my solution, I have a Windows Service called MuskOx.

MuskOx has a project reference to a class library called MuskOx.Errands.

MuskOx.Errands has project references to class libraries called Kctc.BusinessLayer and Kctc.NHiberate.

When I build MuskOx, its output folder gets Kctc.BusinessLayer.dll but not Kctc.NHibernate.dll.

This is confusing the hell out of me. Can anyone clarify the rules of which dlls get copied into output folders when a project is built that has direct and indirect project references to class libraries?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

All referenced dll's including indirect project references will be copied to the output of your project.
Except when you have a reference to an assembly that is deployed in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought. So why is it not coming through?! I've fixed the problem by referencing the Kctc.NHibernate project directly from MuskOx, but I'm still confused.

Comment: Another thing I can think of is that the property "Copy Local" is set to false on the reference to Kctc.NHibernate